# I can't fetch the data from reducer to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action

I'm trying pass the data from reducer to component and receive as props.

But the data return UNDEFİNED, so I have tried console the data on reducer and action, but it's okey. There isn't any problem with the data coming from the API, but it always return to component undefined. Where is my fault?

#### Action

```js
export default ProfileTab;

import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE, API_KEY } from '../config/env';
export const FETCHED_MOVIES = 'FETCHED_MOVIES';

export function fetchMovies() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .get(`${BASE}s=pokemon&apikey=${API_KEY}`)
      .then((result) => result.data)
      .then((data) =>
        dispatch({
          type: FETCHED_MOVIES,
          payload: data.Search,
        }),
      );
  };
}
```

#### Reducer

```js
import { FETCHED_MOVIES } from '../actions/movies';

const initialState = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  movies: [],
  error: {},
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCHED_MOVIES':
      return {
        ...state,
        movies: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

#### Component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { fetchMovies } from '../../actions/movies';

class Case extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    movies: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMovies();
  }

  onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      input: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.movies);

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="movies-root">
          <div className="movies-wrapper">
            <div className="movies-container safe-area">
              <h1>mert</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    movies: state.movies,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchMovies,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Case);
```

Comment: Maybe you should try with https://github.com/redux-utilities/redux-promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in the connect statement:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{fetchMovies})(Case);
```

And remove the `mapDispatchToProps` function from your code.

Dispatching props as an object is quite incorrect. Try this, and it should work.

Comment: also when i edit the mapStateToProps, i can reach the data thnx ! 
        movies: state.moviesReducer.movies

Answer (score 0):

That's because your mapDispatchToProps function should return an object and take dispatch as parameter. Each field in your returned object should contain a function that dispatches your action.

So try something like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchMovies: () => dispatch(fetchMovies())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there's already [an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507702/i-cant-fetch-the-data-from-reducer-to-component/63508521#63508521), I'm not sure how correct it is, as it's completely valid to pass `mapDispatchToProps` the way you did with the latest `react` (16.13.1) and `react-redux` (7.2.1) versions (I'm not sure about earlier versions).

Now, assuming your question contains the whole code, there are two important things missing:

1. Creating the store:

   ```
   import { createStore } from "redux";
   const store = createStore(reducer);
   ```

   and passing it to the `Provider` component:

   ```
   <Provider store={store}>
   ```
2. If you go ahead and do as above, you'll see that `this.props.fetchMovies` emits the following error:

   > Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

   To fix it, do as it says and add a middleware, e.g. [`thunk`](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#async-action-creators):

   ```
   import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
   import thunk from "redux-thunk";
   const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
   ```

What follows is the full code. Note that I "split" `fetchMovies` into two functions: sync and async, for illustrating the difference usage between the two. I also modified your code (made is shorter, mostly) for this answer's readability. You can also [see a live demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-ewjkh):

#### File *app.js*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchMoviesSync, fetchMoviesAsyncMock } from "./api";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMoviesSync();
    this.props.fetchMoviesAsyncMock();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="movies-root">
          <div className="movies-wrapper">
            <div className="movies-container safe-area">
              {this.props.movies.join("\n")}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ movies: state.movies });
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchMoviesSync,
  fetchMoviesAsyncMock
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

#### File *api.js*

```
export const FETCHED_MOVIES = "FETCHED_MOVIES";

export const fetchMoviesSync = () => ({
  type: FETCHED_MOVIES,
  payload: ["movie1", "movie2", "movie3", "movie4"]
});
export const fetchMoviesAsyncMock = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: FETCHED_MOVIES,
    payload: ["movie5", "movie6", "movie7", "movie8"]
  });
};
```

#### File *reducer.js*

```
const initialState = {
  movies: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCHED_MOVIES":
      return {
        ...state,
        movies: state.movies.concat(action.payload)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

#### File *index.js*

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Case from "./app";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

let store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Case />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

#### File *index.html*

```
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```